# Problems with Cassandra when starting Kong

Tags: cassandra, kong

When trying to start [Kong](http://getkong.org) with `kong start` the following error message shows up:

```
[INFO] Using configuration: /etc/kong/kong.yml
[INFO] Proxy port.........8000
       Admin API port.....8001
       Database...........cassandra keepalive=60000 port=9042 timeout=1000 hosts=127.0.0.1 keyspace=kong
[ERR] Cassandra error: Failed to read frame header from 127.0.0.1: closed
```

Why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem happens because Cassandra is not running at the address specified in the `kong.yml` configuration file.

Starting Cassandra and specifying the proper connection settings in `kong.yml` made it work, specifically the `contact_points` property at https://getkong.org/docs/0.5.x/configuration/#databases_available

Comment: You could elaborate for others what the "proper settings" you refer to. For example, you're still using the 'hosts' parameter when current configs reference 'contact_points' instead. Which worked and what was the resolution?

Comment: @MikeS. that's correct - I had to properly configure the `contact_points` property in order to make it work https://getkong.org/docs/0.5.x/configuration/#databases_available - I have updated my answer.